# Group by two case statement with date

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have to group by date for below query, but REG and OT hours are coming on different row for same date. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

I did group by date but its not working.

```
SELECT VP.PERSONNUM AS PERSONID, 
VP.FIRSTNM AS FIRST_NAME, 
VP.LASTNM AS LAST_NAME, 
(select personnum from vp_employeev42 where personnum = vp.homelaborlevelnm6) as FOREMAN_CODE, 
CA.PERSONCSTMDATATXT as SHIFT, 
TO_CHAR(X.APPLYDTM, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS LABOR_DATE, 
VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM3 AS DEPARTMENT, 
CASE WHEN TS.LABORLEVELNAME3 != 'NULL' THEN TS.LABORLEVELNAME3 ELSE VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM3 END AS CHGD_DEPARTMENT, 
CASE WHEN P.NAME = 'US-Regular' THEN SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) ELSE 0 END AS REG, 
CASE WHEN P.NAME = 'US-Overtime' THEN SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) ELSE 0 END AS OT, 
CASE WHEN P.NAME = 'US-Doubletime' THEN SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) ELSE 0 END AS DBL , 
CASE WHEN TS.LABORLEVELNAME4 != 'NULL' THEN TS.LABORLEVELNAME4 ELSE VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM4 END AS ACCOUNT_ID 
FROM VP_EMPLOYEEV42 VP, 
WFCTOTAL X, PAYCODE P, 
PERSONCSTMDATA CA, 
VP_TIMESHTPUNCHV42 TS 
WHERE VP.PERSONID = X.EMPLOYEEID AND 
X.PAYCODEID = P.PAYCODEID AND 
X.EMPLOYEEID = CA.PERSONID AND 
CA.CUSTOMDATADEFID ='13' AND 
X.TIMESHEETITEMID = TS.TIMESHEETITEMID AND 
P.NAME in ('US-Regular','US-Overtime','US-Doubletime') AND 
X.EMPLOYEEID in (select personid from PERSONCSTMDATA where CUSTOMDATADEFID ='14' and PERSONCSTMDATATXT = 'USKEANE') 
and VP.PAYRULENAME in ('USKEANE 10 HR Shift','USKEANE 12 HR Shift','USKEANE 1st Shift','USKEANE 2nd Shift','USKEANE 3rd Shift') 
and X.APPLYDTM between '01-APR-19' and '30-APR-19' 
group by VP.PERSONID, VP.PERSONNUM, VP.FIRSTNM, VP.LASTNM, VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM6, 
X.APPLYDTM, VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM3, CA.PERSONCSTMDATATXT ,VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM4, 
P.NAME, TS.LABORLEVELNAME3, TS.LABORLEVELNAME4 ORDER BY VP.PERSONID, X.APPLYDTM DESC
```

```
{
PERSONID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME FOREMAN_CODE SHIFT LABOR_DATE DEPARTMENT CHGD_DEPARTMENT REG OT DBL ACCOUNT_ID
E0002887 Maria Putnam E0061775 1 10-04-2019 25855 25855 0 4 0 60467
E0002887 Maria Putnam E0061775 1 10-04-2019 25855 25855 4 0 0 60467
E0002887 Maria Putnam E0061775 1 15-04-2019 25855 25855 8 0 0 60467
}
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.) Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example before you start.

Comment: I have added query result, in that there are two rows with same date 10-04-2019, so I want to group by that two rows in single row

Comment: Apparently those data belong to different `VP.PERSONID, VP.PERSONNUM, VP.FIRSTNM, VP.LASTNM, VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM6, 
X.APPLYDTM, VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM3, CA.PERSONCSTMDATATXT ,VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM4, 
P.NAME, TS.LABORLEVELNAME3, TS.LABORLEVELNAME4` groups. Check your data or change grouping.

Comment: How to change grouping?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this:

```
select case p.name when 'US-Regular'    then sum(x.durationsecsqty/3600) else 0 end as reg, 
       case p.name when 'US-Overtime'   then sum(x.durationsecsqty/3600) else 0 end as ot, 
       case p.name when 'US-Doubletime' then sum(x.durationsecsqty/3600) else 0 end as dbl
  from p, x
  where x.paycodeid = p.paycodeid 
  group by p.name
```

But you do not want to differentiate `p.name` in your output. So remove it from `group by` and change `case` part like here:

```
select sum(case p.name when 'US-Regular'    then x.durationsecsqty/3600 else 0 end) as reg, 
       sum(case p.name when 'US-Overtime'   then x.durationsecsqty/3600 else 0 end) as ot, 
       sum(case p.name when 'US-Doubletime' then x.durationsecsqty/3600 else 0 end) as dbl
  from p, x
  where x.paycodeid = p.paycodeid
```

If I were you I would also change old-join syntax to more readable:

```
  ...
  from paycode        p  
  join wfctotal       x  on x.paycodeid = p.paycodeid 
  join personcstmdata ca on x.employeeid = ca.personid 
  ...
  where p.name in ('US-Regular','US-Overtime','US-Doubletime') 
  ...
```

though there are people who prefer old way :)